# Changing text on wordpress multisite

Tags: php, wordpress

I have working on a multisite. One of the sites is english and the other is spanish. I need to change the text of a spanish page but I can't find it anywhere.

The page where it appears the english text is rendered from is front-page.php.

I don't see where the spanish is supposed to go:

```
<div class="mod_a clearfix">
  <h1><i>/</i><i>/</i><i>/</i> <?php _e('TEAMWORK','boot_Strap'); ?></h1>
  <h2><?php _e('Success depends on collaboration','boot_Strap'); ?></h2>
  <p><?php _e('Success is a function of multiple factors – all of which need to come together if world-class performance is to be achieved. It is easy to focus on the race alone – but the conditions for success have been established long before the starting flag drops.','boot_Strap'); ?></p>
</div>
```

How do I change the other version of the site?

Comment: See https://wordpress.org/support/topic/_e. Also, why not post this on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is `php _e`. That `php` function calls a translation string. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e

Your theme should have a `pot` file for the different language strings. See https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/localization/